# PowerPivot multiple columns approximate match

Tags: lookup, powerpivot, dax, approximate

I want to find out the **Member_Status** on the date that a Product was purchased.

Table A contains 3 fields: `Member_Name`, `Member_Status`, `Change_Date` (this is the date the member started to have this status).

Table B contains 3 fields: `Member_Name`, `Product_Purchased`, `Purchase_Date`.

Both tables have multiple records for each member (e.g. a member may have had many different statuses over the years and a member may have purchased many different products on different days) so I cannot use a standard PowerPivot relationship.

I think I need to do an indirect lookup (look up the `Purchase_Date` from Table B and find the closest earlier matching `Change_Date` from Table A FOR the MEMBER that matches in both tables and find the correct `Member_Status` field for each record in Table B. but I have not been able to figure out a formula in PowerPivot to achieve this.

Any suggestions?

Here is a sample data file: 
http://www.files.com/shared/5460044b6d805/HowToRelateTwoTablesWithNonUniqueRecords.zip

Comment: Kerry, could you please post some sample data / link to your workbook?

Comment: can you put it on Dropbox and share public link? or http://www.files.com/

Comment: Here is the file: http://www.files.com/shared/5460044b6d805/HowToRelateTwoTablesWithNonUniqueRecords.zip

Comment: I can see you have found the answer already. Doesn't look very intuitive, yet shows the power of DAX language :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a great blog on this topic at http://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/approximate-match-with-multiple-criteria-in-dax-part-ii/ and figure out the solution. Here is the formula that worked for me.
=calculate(
LASTNONBLANK(Table2[Member_Status],1),
FILTER(
Table2,
Table2[Date]=CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(Table2[Date],1),FILTER(Table2,Table2[Member_Name]=Table1[Member_Name] && Table2[Date]<=Table1[Purchase_Date])
)&& Table2[Member_Name]=Table1[Member_Name]))